# Review: Good Question, Bad English

Tags: discussion, review-queues, questions, english

I've been participating in the reviews for a few days. Yesterday I had a question in the "First Posts" queue, where I just didn't know what to do. From a technical standpoint, it was an interesting question; OP tried hard to explain it and had given a nice example to illustrate it. However, OP was certainly not a native English-speaker, and obviously had trouble expressing himself. I hesitated giving it a downvote, and just skipped it. What do you think I should have done here?

- Try to edit it (aside from the fact, that I'm not a native speaker myself, and have sometimes language related trouble too)
- give it a downvote and a comment?
- give it an upvote

Comment: If you understood what the OP was trying to say and could have made it clearer, even if it wouldn't have been perfect English, editing it would have been OK. You question here is completely clear to me.

Comment: If you think the question can be fixed up to be a good question, and the only real problem is a language barrier, a comment is completely appropriate. Ask for clarification: What didn't the OP express clearly enough? If you think you understand what they mean and can edit it to try to help clarify the question, that's perfectly fine too. If you don't feel confident enough to edit it, then don't- Someone else can down the road so long as they can decipher what the OP means. (This is a point where a comment would be even more useful.)

Comment: @Kendra: that sounds like a good way to go, thanks

Comment: @maze-le based on this post, I think your English is good enough for you to try to fix the other post with a suggested edit.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> try to edit it (aside from the fact, that I'm not a native speaker myself, and have sometimes language related trouble too)

From your post here, it seems like your English is fine and if the post was that bad then you probably could have made it at least a little better by editing (assuming you understood what the OP wanted). If you do your best to fix it up, it may make it more clear, avoid some unnecessary downvotes, and someone with even better English than yourself may come along and fix it up some more.

Since, for now, you would be suggesting an edit, be sure to explain what you are changing and why.

If you don't feel you can make a difference on the post then you are better off walking away and possibly leaving a comment on trying to improve the English to make it more clear.

> give it a downvote and a comment?

Voting is entirely up to you but you seem to think that it is "an interesting question" so I wouldn't downvote it solely on the fact that the OP isn't a native speaker. You could comment and ask if the OP could try to fix it up a little. But if they tried the first time then they might not be able to do much better than what they've done.

*side note on editing-* If the English is really bad and I'm uncertain about some of it, I will often go ahead and fix it the best I can. Then I comment letting the OP know that I tried to help with the grammar but to please let me know if I inadvertently changed the meaning of something in the post.

Comment: +1 especially for edit protocol in cases where you need psychic powers to do the job right on the first try.

Answer (score 2):

What's worth remembering is that Stack Overflow isn't really about individual posters getting individual answers. It's about providing a reference of good questions and good answers to them.

A particular supplicant getting an answer is a beneficial side effect of this.

So generally - use that to inform your thinking. If the question generally has merit, but can be improved, then improve it.

If it's another junk question that doesn't really offer anything new/interesting (even if clearly worded) then down vote or vote to close as appropriate.

I am generally more forgiving of those that aren't working in their primary language than those that are lazy. (And yes, you can tell the difference). But either way - an interesting question deserves collation and answering.

But if you're unsure - "skip" is always acceptable.