# How can I ask other users to edit a question with unclear English?

Tags: support, english

I am not a native speaker of English. And I think this is the case for many other users too. What can I do if I see question on Stack Overflow which is written by non-english speaker and I can hardly understand it because the questioner is not very proficient in English? I don't have the competence in English to edit this question myself, but I would be pleased if someone noticed this question and edit it to clarify. How can I get this question this kind of attention?

Comment: I just wonder if there is a button "offer post for editing".

Comment: I also have found related post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296172/review-good-question-bad-english?rq=1 whose accepted answer advises edit when `you probably could have made it at least a little better by editing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to rely on community involvement. The only way I can think of to actively request an edit is finding a chat room where the members are willing and able to help.  With any luck, they'll put in the extra effort to edit the question instead of closing as "unclear." But as shown by my edit, sometimes all you have to do is wait.

Comment: I heard about chat rooms before but never used or even interested in why they are needed. So thanks for information.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) 
Perhaps put a comment on the question, asking the Original Poster to request some help with editting for fluency and comprehension?

I'm happy to help edit these questions, but usually concerned that I will misinterpret what the OP meant and so change the intended meaning of the question from highly ambiguous or even unintelligible, to specific and intelligible but wrong.

Comment: It's good idea, but currently I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: You're half-way there :-)

Answer (score 1):

Option 2)
Add comments which ask clarifying questions of the OP, so that someone can then edit the Question having been provided guidance as to what the Questioner intended.